# how to know if a post was posted today or yesterday using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

how to know if a date is yesterday or today compared to the current date

> for that I would like to write a function of the kind

```
function poster_on(datetime_post, datetime_now) {
    if (moment.any_function (param ...))
        return "posted yesterday";
    else if(condition)
        return "posted today"
    else
        return "date posted"`
}
```

I am trying to extract the hours in datetime_poster and datime_now and make a comparison

```
let diff = time (). diff (datetime_post, 'hours');
```

If the difference is greater than 23 then return 'yesterday' is good in some cases but not in others. For example if datetime_post is 2015-03-11 14:23:00 and datetime_now 2015-04-11 00:23:00, normally my function should return "yesterday" but it returns "today"

Comment: What are the values of `datetime_post` and `datetime_now`? (and please don't say the value is "date" because it means nothing...)

Comment: @Dekel .. for example datetime_post may be 2015-03-11 14:23:00 and datetime_now is the current date ie moment () (which returns the current date)

Comment: ok, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I try to extract the hours in datetime_poster and datime_now and make a comparison >>`let diff = time (). diff (datetime_post, 'hours');>>` if diffrence is greater than 23 then return 'yesterday' is good in some cases but not in others, for example if datetime_post is worth 2015-03-11 14:23:00 and datetime_now 2015-04-11 00:23:00, normally my function should return "yesterday" but it return "today"

Comment: Update the question with the relevant data and the code you tried already. Comments are not readable when you put code in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `moment(datetime_now).diff(datetime_post, 'days') <= 1`. Actually you don't even need the `datetime_now` you can use just `moment().diff(datetime_post, 'days') <= 1`

Comment: I also found this that works as well https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/05-query/01-is-before.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isSame method.

```
let postdate; //some postdate
if(moment(postdate).isSame(new Date(), "day"){
//same day
}else if (moment(postdate).isSame(moment().subtract(1, "days"), "day"{
 //yesterday
 }else{
  //other
 }
```